# Python Syntax Error, cannot find what i spelled wrong

Tags: python, sockets, syntax-error

i have this line of code in my python socket program, but it throws a syntax error, and for the love of god i cannot find what i spelled wrong.

```py
conn.send(f'{os.path.getsize(f'{os.path.curdir}\\{filename}')}'.encode(FORMAT))
```

Here is the "peek problem" screenshot from visual studio code.

[image]

Comment: The nested `'`s?

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no need to nest f strings:

```
import os
filename = "foo.txt"

x = f"{os.path.getsize(os.path.join(os.path.curdir, filename))}"
print(x)
```

Out:

```
7
```